# Mail subject shows utf-8 encoding

Tags: email, utf-8, sendmail, concrete5

Concrete5.7.5.6 / PHP 5.6.30 / SMTP: yes

I have a custom block that uses the sendmail to send a notification but the subject line shows the utf-8 encoding. The same encoding you see in the logs.

```
=?UTF-8?Q?Brochure=20aanvraag, =20gebouw=2002=20-=20Appartement=20A105?=
```

I'm trying to figure out at what point this fails. (Did not make the block myself.)

```
$mh->setSubject($this->parseString($this->emailSubject));
$mh->setBodyHTML($this->parseString($this->emailContent));
@$mh->sendMail();
```

parseString returns the string with the vars replaced, if I leave it out it just shows the same but without the replacement:

```
=?UTF-8?Q?Brochure=20aanvraag, =20gebouw=20{{=20page::building=20}}=20-=20?= {{ page::name }}
```

Strange part: This only happens on the live server, mails send from localhost version works as expected (clean email subject). - Local php version: 5.6.10

The default formblock doesn't have this problem.

[more info] parseString function

```
protected function parseString($string = null)
{
    if (!$this->currentPage) {
        $this->currentPage = Page::getCurrentPage();
    }
    preg_match_all('/{{ ([a-z]+)::([a-z0-9]+) }}/', $string, $matches);
    if ($matches) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $k => $v) {
            $replacement = $v;
            switch ($matches[1][$k]) {
                case 'page':
                    switch ($matches[2][$k]) {
                        case 'name':
                            $replacement = $this->currentPage->getCollectionName();
                            break;
                        case 'link':
                            $replacement = $this->currentPage->getCollectionLink();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $replacement = $this->currentPage->getAttribute($matches[2][$k]);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'post':
                    $postValue = $this->post($matches[2][$k]);
                    if (trim($postValue) != '') {
                        $replacement = $postValue;
                    }
                    else {
                        $replacement = '';
                    }
                    break;
            }
            $string = preg_replace("/$v/", $replacement, $string);
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: can you post what `varString()`does?

Comment: Added the function in the post.